# Multiple Function Need Same Parameter (how to optimize),

Tags: c++, class, c++11, data-structures

Hi this question might some a little bit stupid(the question title might not be not relevant going to change until found a perfect title), i had spend couple hours figuring this out.

i'll try to explain as details as i could.
First i will give the code of mine first.

File 'main.cpp'

```
using namespace std;

void readFile(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
void showMenu(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
void option1(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
void option2(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
void option3(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
void option4(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
void option5();
int getUserChoice();
int getMonthInput();
int getYearInput();

int main()
{

    Vector<WindLog> Obj;
    readFile(Obj);
    showMenu(Obj);

    return 0;
}

void readFile(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj){

    Date date;
    Time time;
    float s, sr;
    WindLog wLog;
    string token, filename, line;

    ifstream myFile("testfile.csv");
    getline(myFile, line); //to skip header information ;

    if(myFile.is_open()){
        while(getline(myFile, line))
        {
            stringstream ss(line); // <-- pas line to stream

            getline(ss, token,'/'); // <--Token for day;
            date.setDay(atoi(token.c_str()));

            getline(ss, token,'/'); // <--Token for month;
            date.setMonth(atoi(token.c_str()));

            getline(ss, token,' '); // <--Token for year;
            date.setYear(atoi(token.c_str()));

            getline(ss, token,':'); // <-- Token for Hour;
            time.setHour(atoi(token.c_str()));

            getline(ss, token,','); // <-- Token for Minute;
            time.setMinute(atoi(token.c_str()));

            for(int i = 0; i<9; i++)
                getline(ss, token, ',');

            getline(ss, token,','); // <-- Token for WindSpeed
            s = atof(token.c_str());

            getline(ss,token,','); // <-- Token for Solar Radiation
            sr = atof(token.c_str());

            wLog = WindLog(date, time, s, sr);
            VecObj.add(wLog);
        }
    }
    else{cout<<"No File Opened"<<endl;}



}
void showMenu(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj){
    int choice;

    while(true){
        cout << "\t\tOptions Menu" << endl;
        cout << "<------------------------------------------->" <<endl;
        cout << "1) Show Maximum Wind Speed for Specified Month and Year." << endl;
        cout << "2) Show Average Wind Speed of Specified Year." << endl;
        cout << "3) Show Total Radiation in kWh/m^2 for each Month of Specified Year." << endl;
        cout << "4) Print Average Wind Speed and Total Solar Radiation for each month of Specified Year, to File('WindandSolar.csv')." << endl;
        cout << "5) Exit Program." << endl;

        choice = getUserChoice();

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:option1(VecObj); break;
            case 2:option2(VecObj); break;
            case 3:option3(VecObj); break;
            case 4:option4(VecObj); break;
            case 5:option5(); break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid Choice, Try Again"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
int getUserChoice(){
    int temp;
    cout << "Enter Your Choice : ";
    cin >> temp;
    while(cin.fail()){
        cout << "Error, Try Again. " << endl;
        cout << "Enter Your Choice : ";
        cin.clear();cin.ignore(256,'\n');

        cin >> temp;
    }
    return temp;
}
int getMonthInput(){
    int tempMonth;
    bool verify = false;

    while(verify==false)
    {
        cout << "Enter Month : ";
        cin >> tempMonth;

        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cout<<"Input Error, Try Again."<<endl;
            cin.clear();cin.ignore(256,'\n');

        }
        else if(tempMonth < 1 || tempMonth > 12)
        {cout<<"Invalid Month, Try Again."<<endl;}
        else
        {verify = true;}
    }
    return tempMonth;
}
int getYearInput(){
    int tempYear;
    bool verify = false;

    while(verify==false)
    {
        cout << "Enter Year : ";
        cin >> tempYear;

        if(cin.fail())
        {
            cin.clear();cout<<"Input Error, Try Again."<<endl;

            cin.ignore(256,'\n');
        }
        else if(tempYear<=0)
        {cout<<"Invalid Year, Try Again."<<endl;}
        else
        {verify = true;}
    }
    return tempYear;
}


void option1(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj){}
void option2(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj){}
void option3(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj){}
void option4(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj){}
void option5(){exit(0);}
```

Let me explain ( if something not clear please give some comment i'll add more specific detail, just into c++ for about 1 month ).

at main i declare `Vector<windLog> Obj` to store my `windlog` file. then i need to pass it to `void readFile(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);` for some read file and add into the Vector Class i created.

after that the program will goes `void showMenu(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);` 
and showing the menu options and `User` entered choice, from 1 to 5;

one of this function will executed based on user choice.

`void option1(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
void option2(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
void option3(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
void option4(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);`

my question is the parameter of option1 - option4, they has the same parameter and that bother me, i dont know whether if its okay or not.

> If any of my question are not clear, please give me some comment so i could fix it. and if you guys want to give me some advice on my code, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Your title says multiple classes, but the question is about multiple functions. What are you really asking about?

Comment: It looks like you need a class that handles all these operations, with a Vector as a member.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about the title, i have change it. my question about the parameter of option1-4. it takes the same 4 parameter and idk if that okay or any way i can optimize it more.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Only thing I'd do differently is re-order the file to eliminate the need for the forward declarations.

Comment: @user4581301 i’ll look forward to the file thank btw :)

Answer (score 4):

If all options will always take the same parameter, you could put them in a vector and index it with the option.

```
typedef void (*option_fun_t)(Vector<WindLog> &VecObj);
option_fun_t option_fun[] = {option1, option2, option3, option4};

choice = getUserChoice();
option_fun[choice-1](VecObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is perfeclty fine to have the same parameter types in different functions, as long as the functions have different names (which they do). If it really bothers you, you could write *one* function and pass an additional parameter (like `int option`), and then do the processing based on that option, like this:

```
void option(Vector<WindLog>& VecObj, int option)
{
    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            // Processing in case of option 1
            break;
        }

    case 2:
        {
            // Processing in case of option 2
            break;
        }

    case 3:
        {
            // Processing in case of option 3
            break;
        }

    case 4:
        {
            // Processing in case of option 4
            break;
        }

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you input, i’ll look forward at this one an re-evaluate my code.

Comment: I prefer clearly multiple (smaller) functions over one big switch case. Note that OP has already a switch case.

Comment: @Jarod42 I generally agree on having separate functions, however, I was addressing his concern about having multiple functions with the same arguments. Also, there is a case for aggregating multiple functions into one if there is some long-winded (pun not intended) preliminary processing step to perform on `Vector<WindLog>` for all options. In this scenario, you would probably call the processing function from `main()` and then probably do a simple final computation and print your results using a switch statement. Admittedly, these are a lot of unfounded assumptions, but not unrealistic.